# An entity object cannot be referenced by multiple instances of IEntityChangeTracker

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, dbcontext, invalidoperationexception

My Problem is following:
I have two tables with many-to-many relationship:Users, UserRoles and Roles. I'm trying when I'm editing a user, to implement the possibility to set a role to the user. I'm using ASP.NET MVC with EF and in the View I use checkboxes to set the new roles. In the UserController I'm working with UserService, in which I'm adding new roles to the already existed user's roles. The service is working with a repository. I have a Generic Repository, which is working with Unit of work. The values are mapping from the view to the model. When I'm trying to update the roles and user in the database at the same time I got the following error:

> An exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in
>   DAL.dll but was not handled in user code
>   Additional information: An entity object cannot be referenced by
>   multiple instances of IEntityChangeTracker.

```
  public class BaseRepository<T> where T: BaseEntity, new()
  {
      private DbContext db;
      private DbSet<T> dbSet;
      private UnitOfWork unitOfWork;

      // constructors, where I make an instance of Unit of work
      public BaseRepository()
      {
          db = new BookATableContext();
          dbSet = db.Set<T>();          
      }

      public BaseRepository(UnitOfWork unitOfWork)
      {                   
          db = new BookATableContext();
          dbSet = db.Set<T>();
          this.unitOfWork = unitOfWork;        
      }
     //Get User by id
public virtual T GetById(int id)
    {
        return dbSet.Find(id);
    }
      // Update method
      protected virtual void Update(T entity)
      {
          try
          {
              entity.UpdatedAt = DateTime.Now;
              db.Entry(entity).State = EntityState.Modified;                             
              db.SaveChanges();
          }
          catch (Exception e)
          {
              throw e;
          }     
      }
  }
```

---

```
// my implementation of Unit of work
public class UnitOfWork : IDisposable
{
     private BookATableContext context;
     private DbContextTransaction transaction;

     public UnitOfWork()
     {
         this.context = new BookATableContext();
         this.transaction = this.context.Database.BeginTransaction();
     }

     public void Commit()
     {
         if (transaction != null)
         {
             transaction.Commit();
             transaction = null;
         }
     }

     public void RollBack()
     {
         if (transaction != null)
         {
             transaction.Rollback();
             transaction = null;
         }
     }

     public void Dispose()
     {
         if (transaction != null)
         {
             transaction.Dispose();
             transaction = null;
         }
     }
 }
```

---

//UserService code

```
public class UserService:BaseService<User>
{
    public UserService() : base()
    {

    }
    public UserService(UnitOfWork unitOfWork) : base(unitOfWork)
    {

    }

    public List<SelectItem> GetSelectedRoles(List<Role> roles)
    {
        roles = roles ?? new List<Role>();
        return new RoleService()
        .GetAll()
        .Select(r => new SelectItem
        {
            Text = r.Name,
            Value = r.Id.ToString(),
            Selected = roles.Any(ar => ar.Id == r.Id)
        })
        .ToList();
    }
    public List<Role> GetUpdatedUserRoles(List<Role> roles, string[] selectedRoles)
    {
        selectedRoles = selectedRoles ?? new string[0];
        roles = roles ?? new List<Role>();
        return roles = new RoleService(unitOfWork)
        .GetAll()
        .Where(r => selectedRoles.Any(sr => r.Id == Convert.ToInt32(sr)))
        .ToList();
    }
}
```

---

//UserService inherits BaseService, which has the following constructor

```
public class Base`enter code here`Service<T> where T: BaseEntity, new()
{
    private BaseRepository<T> Repository;
    protected UnitOfWork unitOfWork;

    public BaseService()
    {

        this.Repository = new BaseRepository<T>();
    }

    public BaseService(UnitOfWork unitOfWork)
    {
        this.unitOfWork = unitOfWork;
        this.Repository = new BaseRepository<T>(this.unitOfWork);

    }
public T GetById(int id)
    {
        return this.Repository.GetById(id);
    }
```

}

There are lots of references about this error on the net even here on SO, but after reading all those comments and suggestions, I a haven't found a solution or the reason I am getting this error.

Comment: Are you using any specific DI container to resolve your injected dependencies like Unity, Ninject etc?

Comment: Is there any chance to resolve the problem without using DI container, because is not what I am allowed to use?

Comment: See the issue as it looks like to me is that you are injecting the UOW in your base repository. Now every time you create an instance of your concrete repository that inherits from the base its going to resolve the UOW as well. And in the constructor of your UOW you are creating a new context. So you see there could potentially be multiple contexts operating on the same entity and hence the source of your issue

Comment: Do you call `GetByGuid()` to retrieve the user when adding roles to it and passing it into the `Update()` method inside your `BaseController`? if yes, what does `GetAll()` do? If you `BaseService` is creating another `BookATableContext`, this is the problem I just said in my answer.

Comment: No, `GetByGuid()` is a method for another purpose.

Comment: So why did you post this method in your sample code? Please, post the code used to retrieve the user. Also did you read my explanations and tried to do what I suggested? I'm almost sure this is the problem, since I had it in the past.

Comment: @R.A.P. where are you calling `Update()` to pass the user? Show us the code you use to get the user with `GetById`, add the role and call `Update()`.

Comment: @R.A.P. see my edited answer. In short, you can't call `new BookATableContext()` inside `BaseRepository`. You must only call it inside your `UnitOfWork`, to make sure you only have one `BookATableContext` instance. See my answer for more details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a method `Update` in your `BaseRepository` which receives an entity, and somehow attach it to a `DbContext` which is created inside the constructor of this base repository.

You also have a `GetById` method which you call to fetch that user, add roles, and later pass to `Update` method.

The problem is that you have two service classes: UserService and RoleService, both inheriting `BaseService`.

Then you call this:

```
return new RoleService()
.GetAll()
.Select(r => new SelectItem
{
    Text = r.Name,
    Value = r.Id.ToString(),
    Selected = roles.Any(ar => ar.Id == r.Id)
})
.ToList();
```

or this:

```
return roles = new RoleService(unitOfWork)
    .GetAll()
    .Where(r => selectedRoles.Any(sr => r.Id == Convert.ToInt32(sr)))
    .ToList();
```

in both situations `RoleService` won't use the same `DbContext` instance used inside the `Update()` method from `BaseRepository`.

I can afirm this because there are two ways your `RoleService` is using a `DbContext` to get roles:

Since it inherits BaseService, the `BaseService` always creates a new instance of `BaseRepository`, which creates a new instance of `DbContext`.

Since you are using a `UserService` to get the user by id, and using `RoleService` to get roles, these two service classes are not using the same `DbContext`, each one has its own `BaseRepository` with their own `DbContext`.

### TL;DR

You can't get roles from one `DbContext`, and add it to a user queried from another `DbContext`. This will not work:

```
var userService = new UserService();
var user = userService.GetById(1);

var roles = userService.GetSelectedRoles(null);
user.AddRoles(roles);

userService.Update(user);
```

You could fix your code by always using the `DbContext` from your `UnitOfWork`:

```
// Never use this, unless you are using only one entity (e.g user)
// and not using two or more related (e.g users and roles)
// public BaseRepository()
// {
//     db = new BookATableContext();
//     dbSet = db.Set<T>();          
// }

public BaseRepository(UnitOfWork unitOfWork)
{         
    // Don't create a new DbContext instance, use a unique shared instance
    // from UnitOfWork          
    // db = new BookATableContext();
    dbSet = db.Set<T>();
    this.unitOfWork = unitOfWork;   
    this.db = unitOfWork.db;
}
```

and whenever you need to create `UserService` or `RoleService`, use the same `UnitOfWork` instance to make sure there is no 2 instances of DbContext. Also, you might need to make the `db` property of your `UnitOfWork` public (or create a public getter).

So, you need to fix this method as well:

```
public class Base`enter code here`Service<T> where T: BaseEntity, new()
{
    private BaseRepository<T> Repository;
    protected UnitOfWork unitOfWork;

    // Must not use this constructor, we always need the unitofWork to share DbContext
    // public BaseService()
    // {
    //     this.Repository = new BaseRepository<T>();
    // }

    public BaseService(UnitOfWork unitOfWork)
    {
        this.unitOfWork = unitOfWork;
        this.Repository = new BaseRepository<T>(this.unitOfWork);

    }
}
```

So all classes inheriting BaseService must have constructors with UnitOfWork, you can't use the parameterless constructor...also fix this:

```
public List<SelectItem> GetSelectedRoles(List<Role> roles)
{
    roles = roles ?? new List<Role>();
    return new RoleService(this.unitOfWork) // always pass unitOfWork
    .GetAll()
    .Select(r => new SelectItem
    {
        Text = r.Name,
        Value = r.Id.ToString(),
        Selected = roles.Any(ar => ar.Id == r.Id)
    })
    .ToList();
}
```

Example method in your Controller:

```
public ActionResult AddRoleToUser()
{
    var unitOfWork = new UnitOfWork();

    var userService = new UserService(unitOfWork); // This unitOfWork will be passed to RoleService and BaseRepository as well...
    var user = userService.GetById(1);

    var roles = userService.GetSelectedRoles(null);
    user.AddRoles(roles);

    userService.Update(user);

}
```